# How can I use neovim to automate generating pdfs from Rmarkdown?

Tags: vim, automation, r-markdown, neovim

I have been wanting to create a sort of live preview effect when writing Rmarkdown in neovim. I've looked at various plugins that claim to help with this but I have not been able to get any of them working (even after installing them properly. I'm not sure if it's a vim vs neovim thing).

The closest I have come to this is using entr from the terminal before I begin editing my rmd document, but to do this I'd have to manually enter the command:

> echo [file] | entr echo "require(rmarkdown); render('[file]')" | R --vanilla

every time I turn on my computer and for every single file I decide to work on that day.

I've attempted to create various autocmds in my init.vim, but those either don't work at all, don't work the way I would like (i.e vim hangs every time it runs the autocommand, even when running silently), or produce errors.

Is there something wrong I'm doing when writing my autocmds or is there a better method overall I can use to get live previews working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do when working with markdown files in Vim is create a temporary autocmd to recompile my pdf using **pandoc** and then send a `SIGHUP` to **mupdf** to reload the file.

Being in your markdown file, run this:

`:au! BufWritePost <buffer> silent !pandoc % -o your.pdf && pkill -HUP mupdf`

This assumes mupdf is already running in the background showing your.pdf.

If you want it more permanently, you could add the autocmd to your .vimrc, though you have to make sure to just set it up for Rmarkdown files. Then the only step you need to do is open mupdf once.